# Seer working in everything but latest IE browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I'm maintaining an old rails 2.x app that is slated for retirement after this summer.

It uses the Seer gem to create a simple barchart and has always worked like a champ in every browser.

Now, however, it won't work in the most recent versions of IE.  The code itself hasn't changed in two years.  It works in every other browser.

It WILL work in IE in compatibility mode.  The javascript is sent to the browser but the browser won't render it.

Seer is an old gem and this is an old app....I understand this is a bit of a hail mary.

Anyone else run into this problem?  I would post the code but I believe this is one of those questions that will either be instantly recognizable to someone if they've seen it before.

Thanks!

EDIT:  the gist of the js is here: https://gist.github.com/crowell256aa/9200487

Comment: What does the javascript look like?

Comment: the gist is here: https://gist.github.com/crowell256aa/9200487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That gem uses the old and deprecated "barchart" package for drawing charts.  Since that package predates the arrival of IE9, I suspect that it is trying to create VML code in IE 9+, which is probably the cause of the code not working.  The fix for this is to use the modern "corechart" package instead.